Switching limits of a pdf
I have a joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=2x$ for $x<y<x+1, 0<x<1.$ I then tried swapping the limits around and got the following inequalites $y-1<x<y, 0<y<2.$ However, this integrates to 2, so something is incorrect but I can't figure out wher I have gone wrong.

For a question like this, it's almost always a good idea to sketch the region in the $xy$ plane.

Now if you look at how lines of constant $y$ cut this parallelogram, you see that you need different cases for $0 < y \le 1$ and $1 < y < 2$.

Thanks for the picture. I see what you mean by splitting it into two different areas but why does $y−1<x<y,0<y<2$ not satisfy this?
$$ $$
But going along with your advice, for $0<y\le 1$, then $y>x$ and for $1<y<2$ we have $y < x+1$?

I have just verified this by integrating the pdf and getting $1$. I am still unsure about why you would have to split this integral into 2 different parts.

I see why I am incorrect, because taking x=1.8 would suggest $P_{X,Y}(x,y)\not=0$ but it should be $0$. So my next question is how did you know to split it into 2 different inequalites? Is it the shape of the region? And also what region am I describing with my inqualties? $$$$
I went on desmos to check, and it is a parallelogram with a rectangle over it. Should I only take the overlap of these?

The region is a parallelogram. You only need one integral if you integrate with respect to $y$ first. For each $x$, $y$ goes from $x$ to $x+1$ ,so the integral should be
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{x+1} 2x \, dy \, dx.
$$
On the other hand, if your integral with respect to $y$ is on the outside, the $x$-limits change, depending on where $y$ is. For $y$ between $0$ and $1$, $x$ goes from $0$ to $y$. However, for $y$ between $1$ and $2$, $x$ goes from $y-1$ to $1$.
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{1} 2x \, dx \, dy + \int_{1}^{2} \int_{y-1}^{1} 2x \, dx \, dy.
$$
first case
second case

Thanks for the insight, I see where I went wrong now.
